# Twitter: Get External Video Links to Autoplay

Tags: video, twitter, autoplay

Over the last few months, Twitter has had a feature where certain videos will autoplay in your timeline.  We have developed an app that we want to be able to share videos on Twitter and can't find any documentation on how to get these to load properly and then actually autoplay.

We've tried sharing a website link with the video embedded and sharing the mp4 link directly.

We can't find any documentation on Twitters developer portal to say how this can be supported.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Thanks!